# Spring Properties file not auto wiring, @Value values always NULL

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services

I have a Spring web application (RestFul web service)
I have the following in my `applicationContext.xml` to read properties file:

```
 <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="properties" ref="appProperties" />
</bean>

<bean id="appProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:common.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:local.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:${XPLAT_ENV}.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And my Rest API is like this :

```
@Path("/login")
@Component
public class CLSAmple {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("appProperties")
    protected Properties appProperties;


    @Value("${ui.server.endpoint}")
    private String uiservername;


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getLoginInformation() {
        if(appProperties != null){
            System.out.println("AppProperties is NOT null");
            String uiServer = appProperties.getProperty("ui.server.endpoint");
            return uiServer;
        }
        System.out.println("AppProperties is NULL");
        System.out.println("@Value  is " + uiservername);
        return "Hello Java!!";
    }

}
```

But my `@Autowired` `appProperties` and `@Value` to get a particular property is always `NULL`. I have looked into similar posts about injecting values from properties file and tried all possible things suggested but it is still `NULL`.
Also tried Annotation only approach using
`@PropertySource("classpath:common.properties")`
but same results.

Thanks

Edited: Here is the applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:metrics="http://www.ryantenney.com/schema/metrics" 
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
http://www.ryantenney.com/schema/metrics
http://www.ryantenney.com/schema/metrics/metrics.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.cl.connect" />

<context:annotation-config/>
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="properties" ref="appProperties" />
</bean>

<bean id="appProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:common.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Edited to add: My common.properties is in src/main/resources

Comment: Can you the whole of your applicationContext.xml

Comment: JAX WS is instantiating your classes separately from Spring. You'll need to configure integration so that it retrieves them from your Spring context instead.

Comment: Why are you using jax ws when you already use spring? Just use spring restControllers and you don't have to manually configure properties if using spring

Comment: @Plog Added the applicationContext.xml
I need to use jax ws because tis is a module of an existing project and need to follow what the other project uses just to maintain consistency

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis How do I configure integration?

Answer (score 0):

I found what the issue was, like someone mentioned in the comments above,
I had the integration wrong, I added following to my web.xml and it worked:

```
 <context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
```